# After Mac OS update Pycharm django python console doesn't have right environmental variable but the "run server" works fine

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am using pycharm as editor of my django app. Everything was working fine until I updated my mac os. After that a lot of settings got messed up for the python interpreter.

I managed to fix most of the issue and now I can "run the server" correctly. However, I still can't get the python console to run properly.

When I open the console and I try to import a model, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

The thing that kills me is that I have the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set in my django server environmental variables so it's if the python console was not picking that up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I added export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mywebsite.settings to my system env variable and it worked. It's a work around I know, but at least.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is a bit of a pain, I suggest checking out the below settings and updating the options for both your settings file AS WELL as your manage.py file and make sure your manage.py file is pointing to your settings.

`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mywebsite.settings")`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support.html#4902d6de

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/console-django-console.html

Comment: mmmm my manage.py does have that line already (and indeed it works fine). I can also do python manage.py shell and it will work.

It must be something very specific of pycharm python console but I can't fully understand the two links you shared or how can they help me...any idea/support?

Comment: Found a solution. I added `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mywebsite.settings` to my system env variable and it worked. It's a work around I know, but at least.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the settings and search for django console.
Add environment variable and point to your settings file.
It should be a permanent fix.
Hope it helps

[image]